# ¿Como hago para validar un caracter especial seguido de mayusculas JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Quiero por medio de expresiones regulares validar que siempre una cadena empiece en mayuscula y que despues de un guion haya un caracter en mayuscula y mas de uno en minuscula, por ejemplo

"Hola-Mundo-Bienenidos-&observadores#2020" entonces con la expresion solo me debe tomar "H""-Mun""-Bie"

estoy realizando de la siguiente manera:

```
var texto1 = "Hola-Mundo-Bienenidos-&observadores#2020";
    var validar = /[A-Z]-[A-Z]([a-z]){2}/g;


    if (validar.test(texto1)) {
        document.write("Correcto");
        var prueba = texto1.match(validar);
        console.log(prueba);

    }
```

pero solo no me aparece nada
Muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Cristian, no estoy seguro de entenderte, ¿ qué esperas que pase en el ejemplo ? ¿ Qué esperas que se muestre en `console.log(prueba);`  ?

Comment: se debe mostrar "H""-Mun""-Bie"

Comment: Pero la regex solo devolverá true o false si es que encuentra que el *patrón* establecido se presenta en la cadena, mas  no lo que buscas que salga

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa esta expresión:

```
var validar = /([A-Z]|-[A-Z][a-z]{2})/g;
```

Básicamente lo que hace es expresar que una parte de la cadena empieze por un carácter alfabético en mayúscula o por un guión  (-) seguido de un carácter alfabético en mayúscula y 2 carácteres en minúscula

Comment: Por favor considera editar y argumentar tu aporte